# Split DataFrame as per series values

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working on a Netflix dataset where some columns having comma-separated values.
I would like a have count of shows released per country but data is like

[Image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbsso.png)

How do I split the data and make it countrywide like 1 show releases in 3 countries(Norway, Iceland, United States) then row should come 3 times with a single country in the country column.

| show_id | country |
| --- | --- |
| s5 | Norway |
| s5 | Iceland |

NOTE: Using pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can split the comma-separated string to the list and then apply 'explode' to that column.

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('country')
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my purpose. I require the number of shows released per country.

Comment: it worked for comma separation but showing single series in a data frame.

Comment: did you try the 'explode' function on the country column after splittiling?

Comment: I think you probably want to do `df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',')` (not `df= df['country'].str.split(',')`)